# Getting a bean with all its dependencies using Spring ServiceFactoryBean

Tags: spring, factory

I have custom factory class to get a bean using Spring's service factory bean. However, the bean that I want to get from this factory bean, has nested bean dependencies. My question is how do I get a bean from this factory with all its nested dependencies met?

```
Spring Config : 

<bean id="beanFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean">
  <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="com.example.MyBeanFactory">
</bean>


Public class MyBean
    {
       JobBuilder builder;
    }




Public interface MyBeanFactory
    {
      MyBean getMyBean();
    }
```

Now when I do `MyBeanFactory.getMyBean()`... I want have to have MyBean instance that includes `JobBuilde` instance, inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the implementation class as any other class in the Spring application - just autowire any dependencies that you need. One suggestion I have is to define an interface for the bean class. Example:

```java
public interface MyBean {

  void doStuff();
}
```

Provide an implementation:

```java
@Component("defaultMyBean")
public class DefaultMyBean {

  @Autowire
  JobBuilder jobBuilder;

  public void doStuff() {
   // do stuff with jobBuilder
  }
}
```

And then the factory interface:

```java
public interface MyBeanFactory {

  MyBean getMyBean();
}
```

Configuration remains unchanged.